# Error when inserting data into database with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc, mariadb

When I try to insert a line in my database, I get the following error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukMrd.png)

This is the code:

```
try
{
    DateTime date = new DateTime(2018, 02, 15, 07, 06, 00);

    using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
    {
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO Kassatickets (id, datum, korting, totaal) VALUES 3, '2018-02-15 07:06:00', " + kt.KortingId + ", " + kt.Totaal, con);                 

        con.Open();
        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Er zijn geen wijzigingen uitgevoerd!!");
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw e;
}
```

First I thought the problem was the format of the date, but when I insert this line directly into the database through phpmyadmin, there is no problem.

Probably this is easy to solve, but I can't find the problem...

Comment: Please use parametrized query.

Comment: Try following: OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO Kassatickets (id, datum, korting, totaal) VALUES (3, '2018-02-15 07:06:00', " + kt.KortingId + ", " + kt.Totaal + ")", con);

Comment: You Just forget to use braces "()" after values in your SQL syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emphasize on parameterized queries:

**Method 1:**

```
using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
{
    var query ="INSERT INTO Kassatickets (id, datum, korting, totaal) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";     

    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, con);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("id", OdbcType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = 3;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("datum", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = "2018-02-15 07:06:00";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("korting", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = kt.KortingId;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("totaal", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = kt.Totaal;
    con.Open();
    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Er zijn geen wijzigingen uitgevoerd!!");
    }
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
{
    var query = "INSERT INTO Kassatickets (id, datum, korting, totaal) VALUES (@id, @datum, @korting, @totaal)";

    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 3);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datum", "2018-02-15 07:06:00");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@korting", kt.KortingId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totaal", kt.Totaal);
    con.Open();
    if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 0)
    {
        throw new Exception("Er zijn geen wijzigingen uitgevoerd!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i allready tried that, but it didn't work at that moment. Now it worked, i only had to change the UniqueIdentifier to Int.